# componentDidUpdate not called after render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I need to hook-up to the component update event, to fetch fresh data. Hence, I wrote something like:

```
...
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  const values = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search),
    type = values['type'];
  this.props.loadChallengeDetails(type);
}

shouldComponentUpdate() {
  console.log('shouldComponentUpdate');
  /* if (this.props.location.search !== nextProps.location.search) {
    console.log('should reload report');
    const values = queryString.parse(nextProps.location.search),
      type = values['type'];
    this.props.loadChallengeDetails(type);
  } */
  return true;
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  console.log('componentDidUpdate');
  if (this.props.location.search !== prevProps.location.search) {
    console.log('should reload report');
    const values = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search),
      type = values['type'];
    this.props.loadChallengeDetails(type);
  }
}

render() {
  console.log('details:', this.props.details);
...
```

This page/view is a "detail" for a "master" page, if you will. Depending on the value of `type` passed in the query, it fetches some data.

On first render it happens fine. Both `shouldComponentUpdate` or `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle methods are invoked. When I go back then view details for another record, however, it shows stale data. Console log prints `details` inside render, but does not call either `shouldComponentUpdate` or `componentDidUpdate`.

What am I doing wrong? Please advise.

Comment: what does `this.props.loadChallengeDetails` do?

Comment: loads `this.props.details` from redux store.

Comment: Are you missing the `withRouter` wrapper to the component?

Comment: @madebydavid why should `withRouter` even matter, if `render()` gets called?

Comment: @IgorShmukler - `this.props.location` will only be set if you are using the `withRouter` HOC

Comment: @madebydavid since I am already getting `this.props.location`, one would assume that the router is not the problem.

Comment: @IgorShmukler - I didn't see the `withRouter` in your included snippets so assumed it could be missing. If your component is not updating then perhaps your props are not updating. Anyway, good luck